# Нужен совет по парсингу лога

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый вечер нужен совет по парсингу лога.Есть лог:

```
http://devilscity.combats.com/logs.pl?log=1393349213.0236
```

В данном логе мне надо спарсить участников данного боя,точнее их ники.Для этого я воспользовался библиотекой **simple_html_dom.**. Вот код с помощью которого я извлекаю ники участников боя.

```
if(!empty($_POST['url'])){

    $url = $_POST['url'];
    $decodedLog = zlib_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    $log = new simple_html_dom();
    $log->load($decodedLog);

    $matches = $log->find('font.B9 font');

    if(count($matches)!= null){
        for($i=0;$i<count($matches);$i++){
            $player = $matches[$i]->find('text',0);

            echo $player."<br>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Бой закончен";
    }
}
```

Дальше имея ник мне надо открыть страничку с инфой персонажа и прочесть кое какие параметры.Ссылка на персонажа выглядит вот так `http://devilscity.combats.com/inf.pl?1272404620`.Это цифровая ссылка,но вместо айди персонажа так же можно подставить его и ник и информация так же отобразится.Проблема заключается вот в чем,есть бои в которых присутствуют боты всяких локаций,и прежде чем открывать инфу персонажа,мне нужно узнать бот это или игрок.Так вот подскажите как можно решить данную задачу? Можно составить массив с названиями всех ботов локаций и перед открытием ссылки проверять на наличие в этом массиве данного бота,но там и массив будет из 300 элементов,поэтому мне показалось что это плохая идея.Второй вариант каждый ник в логе формируется вот такой функцией **drwfl("Саргон",1272404620,"12",20,"Outcasts")**,отсюда можно было бы считать айди и уже сравнивать бот или игрок,так как у них разная длина айди,но тут опять же проблема если лог открыт на какой то странице допустим 10-ой,то уже не удасться извлечь эти данные,прийдется организовать переход по страницам пока не найду в них данную функцию! Вижу что много всего написал,заранее извините,но всетаки надеюсь на подсказку!

Comment: "Саргон промахнулся и непобедимый Тяжелый Пещерный Ползун остановил тычок ручкой топора по щиколотке." - куда я зашел и где мои вещи

Comment: Не понял вопроса!

Comment: Гипотеза: ники игроков всегда в `<span class="b1">...</span>`, а ботов — в `<span class="b2">...</span>`

Comment: Это классы для подсветки ника,нападшая сторона подсвечивается синим цвето,тоесть class="b1",защищающаяся "b2"

Comment: Кроме как создать массив со всеми именами ботов,других вариантов не вижу,даже если организовать переход по страницам,то лог может быть и на 200 и 300 страниц,из за 1-го ника проделыать такую работу тоже не вариант( Если у кого то есть подсказка буду рад выслушать!